# Truncate object causing storage usage error

Tags: data-storage

[image]

I truncate custom object, and now got this issue with data storage, and can't delete it. Someone can help?

Comment: did you try delete recycle bin as well?

Comment: @gold Yes, i am.

Comment: can you elaborate your question with more details?

Comment: Yes we had a trigger that cause us errors, and i truncate object, and after that it made that object __trunc record type with deleted records. Now i can''t find how to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will eventually be purged if you wait for 15 days, or you can remove the data immediately by going to Setup > Customize > Objects > Deleted Objects (bottom of the Custom Object list), and clicking on Erase. Once erased, the data is permanently deleted and can never be recovered.